# how to add Linebreak to a string in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net

I tried everything, but nothing seems to work!

How the do I put a breakline?!

```
Dim textMsg as String
textMsg = Body.text & Environment.Newline & _ q1.text & Environment.Newline & _ q2.text & Environment.Newline & _ q3.text & Environment.Newline & _ q4.text '
```

please help

(with corrent code I get an error cuz of the  & Environment.Newline & _ ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats the right one:

& (vbCrLf) &

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this `asp.net`, I'll guess that this newline should appear in a web page. In that case, you need to remember that you are creating **html** rather than plain text, and *html ignores all whitespace*... including newlines.  If you view the source for your page, you'll likely see that the new lines do make it to your html output, but they are ignored, and that's what is supposed to happen. If you want to *show* a new line in html, use a `<br>` element:

```
textMsg = Body.text & "<br>" & _ q1.text & "<br>" & _ q2.text & "<br>" & _ q3.text & "<br>" & _ q4.text
```

The code above will place the text on several lines. It's interesting that if you view the source now, you'll see that everything is all on the same line, even though it uses several lines for display.

Comment: dosent work, when I get the email from the code, it still shows all answers in a line. with no break lines

Comment: @pelleg, you might want to post your email code segment - you might be having other issues.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a br:

```
textMsg = Body.text & "<BR/>" & _ q1.text & "<BR/>" & _ q2.text & "<BR/>" & _ q3.text & "<BR/>" & _ q4.text
```

Or you can try:
Str & VBNewLine OR Str & VBCrLf

Or set the email message to html. The the 
 will work.

Comment: 6<br>TestData1<br>3<br>4<br>5
this is the email I receive once I use the code above              this is the code:
textMsg = Body.text & "<br>" & q1.text & "<br>" &  q2.text & "<br>" & q3.text & "<br>" & q4.text '

any ideas?

Comment: You should remove the asp.net tag. However have you tryed:
Str & VBNewLine OR
Str & VBCrLf

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim textMsg as String
textMsg = Body.text & vbNewLine
```

Answer (score 0):

I preffer .Net Style:

```
& Environment.NewLine &
```

It's Is exactly the same that

```
& (vbCrLf) &
```